# ios subview positioning incorrect in pageViewController on first draw

Tags: ios, view, positioning, subview

I have a viewcontroller nested in a pageviewcontroller that I want to subdivide into two sections (top + bottom). I correctly assign the frames for the respective views (code below), but the first time it's rendered is incorrect. When I swipe away and then back again, the rendered screen is then correct. Any idea what's going on?

[image]

[image]

```
-(void) viewDidLoad 
{

self.controller1 = [self.storyboard    
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"controller1"];
self.controller2 = [self.storyboard 
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controller2"];

[self.view addSubview:self.controller1.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.controller2.view];

[self addChildViewController:self.controller1];
[self addChildViewController:self.controller2];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear 
{
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
BOOL navigationBarHidden = [self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden];
CGRect navigationBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect viewSize = self.view.frame;    

self.controller1.view.frame = 
     CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.size.width, screenBounds.size.width);

self.controller2.view.frame = 
     CGRectMake(0, screenBounds.size.width,
                             screenBounds.size.width, applicationFrame.size.height - screenBounds.size.width);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. The issue isn't with the view controller that showed the split screen, but my custom pageviewcontroller.

I was adding the pageviewcontroller children in -viewDidLoad rather than -viewDidAppear. The difference is that -viewDidLoad did not have the correct dimensions of the superview and so all children view were calculated incorrectly.